# Can I get the current price in a Pine Script indicator as it processes historical bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am writing an indicator for TradingView using Pine script. Indicators run the script over all of the bars in the displayed chart but I want to have a variable that has the current price so that I can calculate the support and resistance at the current price as I process through all of the historical charts. Is there a way to do this.ie when processing a historical bar if I wanted to know how far that bar is from the current price I might have something like:

```
var float currentPrice = ????
distance_toNow = currentPrice - close
```

I've looked at the reference info and google and only found reference to using close/high etc which obviously relate to the bar being processed but not the current price (unless you are processing the last bar of the chart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Your script will be executed starting from the very first available bar. And you can only access to what is available on your chart.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear; obviously the current price is shown eventually on the chart as the last bar but you are confirming that if I'm processing an historical bar there is no way to access the current price (ie close for the last bar of the chart)